the maximum stream in the streaming network
Decide whether the following statement is true or false. If the statement is true, give a brief explanation, and if false, give a counterexample.
Let G be an arbitrary streaming network with a source s, a drain t, and a positive integer bandwidth ce for each edge E. If f is the maximum flow s-t in G, then f saturates every edge leaving s (that is, for all edges e leaving s, the condition f(e) = ce is satisfied).
I will be glad of any help

Looks like homework, and not even programming homework.
